# Can we add a scroll bar in text component of Fabricjs?

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

We have requirement to have scroll bar for fabricjs text component.
So that user can fixed width and height of the component and if text is not fitting in that width or height then appropriate scroll bar should be appeared instead of increasing width or height as per text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As everything is drawing on canvas, I think it is not possible to show a scroll bar for text.